# Creating dependent comboxes based on relational data in worksheet rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a UserForm to record Sales Leads.

One of the comboboxes on the UserForm records the "Customer Code" from the "customers" worksheet. Another of the comboboxes contains a list of contacts from the "contacts" worksheet

Each row on the "Contact" worksheet contains the "Customer Code" (you may see where this is going by now!)

The "customers" worksheet contains a unique list of customers, however the "Contact" Worksheet contains numerous contact names per customer.

I need the Contacts combobox to only display contacts based on the selection of customer code from the customer code combobox.

Currently, the customers combobox is populated when the userform is intialized using the below code

```
cbxCustList.RowSource = "Customers!A2:B" & Sheets("Customers").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

The contacts box is also populated when the form is initialized

```
cbxConList.RowSource = "Contacts!A2:B" & Sheets("Contacts").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

The issue here is that all contacts will always be displayed, the requirement is for the contacts to be filtered based on customer selection.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is unfortunately *too broad* to be reasonably answerable on this forum - this site is all about *specific* coding issues, not whiteboard general-idea design. Are you able to populate the customer codes box? *How* are you populating them? Are you handling the box' `Change` event? Or are you just struggling to come up with a proper data source for the contact box?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will try to elaborate on your specific questions in the hope I can provide enough detail! 

The customer code and contacts comboboxes are populated when the UserForm is initialised 

 cbxCustList.RowSource = "Customers!A2:B" & Sheets("Customers").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

The contacts combobox is populated in the same way

cbxConList.RowSource = "Contacts!A2:B" & Sheets("Contacts").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

The issue is that the contacts list using the above logic always displays all contacts

Comment: As a housekeeping point, am I best raising a new question with this detail?

Comment: Best [edit] your question to make it as detailed as possible :)

Comment: Edited, apologies.. I don't know what I don't know! Would including the data structure in my worksheets be helpful?

Comment: What I understand is that you have to repopulate Contract combo box with filtered Customer code for a particular customer (selected in customer combo) using Customer combo box change event. To work out the required the code the the layout/details  of contract list along with customer code is required. May please add the details of same or image..

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have solved this now using advanced filtering, M2 is populated from the customer combobox.

```
Dim r As Integer
r = 2
    RefData.Range("M2") = cbxCustList.Value

            Sheets("Contacts").Columns("A:B").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
            CriteriaRange:=RefData.Range("M1:M2"), CopyToRange:=RefData.Range("O1:P1"), Unique:=False
```

cbxCon.Clear

Do Until RefData.Cells(r, 16).Value = ""

```
cbxCon.AddItem RefData.Cells(r, 16).Value
   r = r + 1
```

Loop
End Sub